# selenium.WebDriverException throw failure code 0x80004005 when using a withFrame() method in Firefox

Tags: webdriver, geckodriver, geb, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am creating a test suite for a web site (implemented using node and Angular) that gathers user input. Some of the input is in the form of text box with editing capabilities (similar to this one used in stack overflow). The code that creates the editable box is

```
<div id="mceu_30" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;"> 

<iframe id="ui-tinymce-9_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;"></iframe>

<html> <head><style>...</style></head> <body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="ui-tinymce-1" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p></body> </html>

</div>
```

For simplicity I have removed all the  section.

I am using Geb/Spock framework for test. The specific piece of code that checks the above element is

```
 withFrame(OppBackgroundBox){$("body", id:"tinymce") << Background }
```

Where 'Background' is a string defined previously in the test script, and OppBackgroundBox is a page element defined as

```
  OppBackgroundBox{$(By.xpath('//iframe[@title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help"]'),0)}
```

I identify the element by the title because the id of the frame changes with the browser (//*[@id="ui-tinymce-9_ifr"]* for Mozilla, but //*[@id="ui-tinymce-1_ifr"* for Chrome).

All works fine and well when running the test in Chrome, however, when using Firefox (65.0.1 for Mac) I get the following error

> Condition failed with Exception:
>
> withFrame(OppBackgroundBox){$("body", id:"tinymce") << Background } 
>   |            | 
>   |          pages.app.OpportunitiesAdminCreatePage -> OppBackgroundBox: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator
>
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [Exception... "Component
>   returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsITextInputProcessor.beginInputTransactionForTests]"  nsresult:
>   "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   chrome://marionette/content/event.js :: getTIP_ :: line 429"  data:
>   no] Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'Carless-MacBook-Pro.local',
>   ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c3c:ed6e:6d05:b45d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
>   'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '11.0.1' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion:
>   65.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID:
>   30057, moz:profile: /var/folders/10/vbth59yn0v1...,
>   moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin:
>   false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform:
>   MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 18.2.0, rotatable: false,
>   setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts:
>   {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000},
>   unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify} Session ID:
>   62b25df0-58cf-db4f-9d3c-12a1b12820ce
>
> at CreateProgramProjectOpp.Publish Opportunity:
>   '#TitleData'(CreateProgramProjectOpp.groovy:195)

(where 195 refers to the *withFrame(OppBackgroundBox){$("body", id:"tinymce") << Background }* line of code)

The error message above is a bit garbled, but associated to **OppBackgroundBox** is the message

*pages.app.OpportunitiesAdminCreatePage -> OppBackgroundBox: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator*

So the problem is not about WebDriver being unable to locate the element.

The version of the different components appear in the error message. The Gecko driver version is 0.24.0

At this moment I do not know if this is a problem with WebDriver, Geb or some configuration/versioning error on my part.

Has anybody found this problem and a workaround? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful. You can just edit your question, BTW. I cannot run your incoherent code snippets, unfortunately. I suggest you make this problem reproduceable, then you can expect much better answers. Otherwise you will get either no feedback at all or wild speculation, none of which would help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your Firefox setup and does not have anything to do with Geb. The underlying error from the browser is:

> Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsITextInputProcessor.beginInputTransactionForTests]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/event.js :: getTIP_ :: line 429" data: no

I would suggest googling for parts of the error and seeing what this gives you. It will most likely be something to do with your Firefox state or an incompatibility between the version of FF and the version of Gecko driver binary you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I searched and the few entries regarding failure code: 0x80004005 seem to point that is catch-all Firefox error. I still was not sure if the error was caused by Firefox itself or by any other of the moving pieces (Geb, the config files...), Thanks again, as your reply at least significantly narrows the problem.